# Button in the right corner of MapFragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, admob

what I want to do is add Button in the bottom|left corner of MapFragment v2.

The problem is that my MapFragment is inside LinearLayout because there is also AdView below it so I cannot work with PARENT aligns.

My code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.powa.Activites.MapActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mailBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/map"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/map"
            android:text="MAIL" />
    </RelativeLayout>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/map"
    android:background="@color/black"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="XOXOXOXO" />
```

When i use it like that my MapFragment does not appear at all.

Desired look below.

```
 _____________________
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|     MapFragment    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
| {Button}           |
|____________________|
|                    |
|       AdView       |
|____________________|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weights work only in **Linear-layout**, so provide a height and remove weight on map fragment

```
   <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mailBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/map"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/map"
            android:text="MAIL" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Oh that was too obvious >.<
Thanks mate works like charm now!

Answer (score 1):

You could just put everything inside a **RelativeLayout**, set the AdView to

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

and the MapFragment with

```
android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Change your `fragment` as `match_parent` and remove `android:layout_weight="1"`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mailBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/map"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/map"
        android:text="MAIL" />
</RelativeLayout>
```